Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String in Spring v6.1
When I upgraded to Spring v6.1 from v6.0, I encountered the following error when starting my project.
Everything works well in Spring v6.0.
[ERROR] 2024-06-29 07:41:58,242 [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getTypeForFactoryBeanFromAttributes(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:86) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:837) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:663) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:534) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:138) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394) ~[spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274) [spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102) [spring-web-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3997) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4424) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:599) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:571) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:654) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1130) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1933) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:10.1.25]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1041) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:425) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1629) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:303) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:109) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:385) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:332) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:776) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:772) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1203) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1193) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:10.1.25]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:749) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:203) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:415) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:874) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:164) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:757) [catalina.jar:10.1.25]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345) [bootstrap.jar:10.1.25]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473) [bootstrap.jar:10.1.25]

To reproduce the project with minimal setup, you can use the following commands on the voj project.
Please make sure that you have g++, java, and maven installed.
git clone https://github.com/hzxie/voj
cd voj/judger
# The error can be reproduced in this commit.
git reset 9726a05 --hard

mvn package -DskipTests
java -jar target/voj.judger.jar


Updating the mybatis-spring JAR to version 3.0.3 resolves this issue. The dependency configuration in pom.xml is provided below.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>


In my case, the valid solution did not work. This was the version of spring-data-jpa dependency that did not match the right one to be used with Spring version 6.1.
Hoping it will help someone else.
